# Merge multiple images horizontally in PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, automation, file-format, adobe-bridge

I have a bunch of folders with contents ranging from four images to fifteen images each. I am looking to create horizontal composites of each folder with the file names without extension under each image. All images are sized exactly the same.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to export from one folder with five images-
[image: Horizontal Composite]

The closest I can get to automating this is by using Photoshop's **Automate → PDF Presentation** tool and then place the pages side by side manually. Is there any way I can use actions to automate merging the PDF pages together? Or possibly a way to change Photoshop's PDF Presentation tool so that it does that in the first place?

I am also looking to change the font that Photoshop uses to write each filename if possible. I'm open to suggestions that don't involve the PDF Presentation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Output` tab in Adobe Bridge does this (see the pink dots below):

- You can select for instance 12 images, use the `Layout` section to select 12 columns and 1 row. You can also arrange these in a grid by doing a 3 rows x 4 columns or similar setup.
- In the `Overlays` section you can include the filename without extension and customize the font, font size, etc.
- Set your page size to A4 landscape or something similar in the `Document` section. For a larger number of images the resulting PDF will be multipage.
- Plus some other options you can play with.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this will do exactly what I need! Thank you. I'll mark this as accepted once I try it out.

Comment: I downloaded the Output Module and it worked like a charm. Thank you